# Apply to each element in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

Since each series in the data frame is of tuple, I need to convert them into one number. Basically I have something like this:

```
price_table['Col1'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

But I actually need to do this for each column. x itself is a tuple but it has only 1 number inside, so I need to return x[0] to get its "value" which is of format float instead of tuple.

In R, I will put `axis = c(1,2)` but here seems that putting 2 numbers in axis doesnt work:

```
price_table.apply(lambda x: x[0],axis = 1)
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Is there anyway to apply this simple function to each element in the data frame?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap)

Answer (score -1):

For me the following works well:

```
"price_table['Col1'].apply(lambda x: x[0],1)"
```

I do not use the axis. But, I do not know the reason.